# Spring Security basic auth exception lead to unwanted /error page call

Tags: spring, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have simple spring-boot rest api service with following security config:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().disable();

    http.csrf().disable();

    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/Events/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(String.format("%s/**", restApiDocPath)).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(String.format("%s/**", swaggerPath)).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/users/**").hasAuthority(SmUserRole.ROLE_ADMIN_STR)
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();

    return http.build();
}
```

Unauthorized access to /api/users/ return 401 as expected but in logs I have request to /error url and AccessDeniedException in result:

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/users/?page=0&size=20
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /api/users/?page=0&size=20] with attributes [hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')]
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@394122fd
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error?page=0&size=20
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error?page=0&size=20
a.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator : filter invocation [/error] denied for AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

I dont have /error endpoint in this service. What's the cause of this behavior?

BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint adds "WWW-Authenticate" header and sends UNAUTHORIZED error response, there is nothing about /error.

Comment: Spring Boot will, by default, call an error ("/error) endpoint in case of an error. You can change this behaviour by, for example, providing your own global exception handling class (see https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring ) or providing an endpoint for /error.